# Gatsby not inferring graphql field if all nodes happen to be null on that field

Tags: gatsby

I have some conditional logic my gatsby `onCreateNode` that results in something like this:

```
exports.onCreateNode = async ({ node, actions }) => {
  // Other stuff...

/* If all `embed` results are null here,
 * the field will not be created on the graphql schema
 */
    const embed = await getFormEmbedForNode(node)

    actions.createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `embed`,
      value: embed
    })

  }
}

const getFormEmbedForNode = async node => {
/* If this test is true for all nodes, the field will not be created
 * returning "" avoids this problem
 */
  if (past(node.startDate)) {
    return null

  } else {
    const embedResult = await client.getArbitrary(
      node.links.embedHref
    )
    return embedResult
  }
}
```

While testing in an environment where the new field was `null` on everything the gatsby build broke- even though no pages were being generated to use that field, because their page queries were not recognized as a valid part of the gatsby schema. My workaround has been passing an empty string which convinces the relay compiler in the background that the field is a `String`, but is there a way to do this explicitly rather than relying on a sentinel value?

I've looked at the gqlType creation docs [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-gql-type/#gqltype-creation) and it seems like there might be a way to do this, but I'm confused about the multiple uses of `fields` in relation to gatsby nodes & the accompanying schema.

For posterity, the resulting error during building looks like

```
 ERROR #85907  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

- Unknown field 'embed' on type 'MyNodeTypeFields'.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/

Comment: @ksav thanks - I'll give that a look. Gatsby has simultaneously great and tricky docs, especially when it comes to some terms that are sort of overloaded (`node` and schema creation vs gqlType creation come to mind right now) (& I'll update with an answer here when I get it together).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to handle this, as suggested by @kav above, was to implement `createSchemaCustomization` as documented [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#nested-types). This ensures that those fields will be set regardless of whether gatsby's relay compiler thinks they are empty:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type EventFields {
      slug: String!
      formEmbed: String
    }
    type Event implements Node {
      fields: EventFields
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```